# Use Java to get DNS used to connect to a socket

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, dns

I'm working on a proxy-related project and I need to be able to do the something along the following lines with java:

Person connects on the port of the proxy -> proxy gets the record they used to connect 'serv1.website.com' and then forwards the resulting packets through to a different port/internal ip address

At the same time it would have to be able to take requests from 'serv2.website.com' and forward them a different port/internal ip address

Is this possible in java?

Comment: Is HTTP involved here?

Comment: No. 99% of the time it's going to be something not related to HTTP (usually UDP/ETC)

Comment: Hold on -- you mean you need to handle TCP as well as UDP?

Comment: Usually, yes, although just UDP is fine

Comment: Well, it is possible, yes, but it will require quite a bit of work. ie, working with asynchronous I/O etc. Exciting stuff to work with, but far from being simple ;)

Comment: I don't care if it isn't simple. I just need to be able to do it :p Care to go into depth on how this would be possible?

Comment: If it is possible, how do you do it?

Comment: Hold on. Are you aware that two host names can resolve to a single IP address? Hint: at the socket level, you only know about the IP address, you _do not_ know the name; this is why HTTP has the `Host` header. How do you intend to deal with that when dealing with other protocols than HTTP?

Comment: That's what I was trying to figure out :/ The main reason for wanting to set the proxy up is that I have applications that would do better with SRV records but don't support them :/

Comment: This is becoming very complicated... If remote applications are unaware of your proxy, you cannot possibly expect them to use it efficiently. The only solution I see is that different hostnames resolve to different IP addresses, and listen on different sockets. But I surmise this is not what you want either. You have a chiken and egg problem here.